# Need Query to Calculate Data from Previous in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I have below sample data table in SQL Server

[image]

Below is my expected result to calculate results in Consumption column

[image]

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you want?

Comment: will item always be present? example: you have item 2, there will always be item 1 to calculate consumption? also which version of sql are you working on? I've done something similar before but not sure if it will work for different dbms

Comment: in your example consumption for item 1 should also be 10, right? Otherwise I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I think it's a starting value and he wants to calculate difference between prev value and current, seeing as there is no previous value for item 1 the difference is 0

Answer (score 1):

the query you need uses a join with the same table:

```
select A.Item, A.Date, A.reading, A.Reading - isnull(B.reading,0) as Consumption
from TABLENAME A
left join TABLENAME B on A.ITEM = B.Item+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in mysql and it works, if you need it for a different dbms let me know: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea1fd/15)

```
select t1.item, t1.mydate, t1.reading, 
       coalesce((t1.reading - t2.reading),0) as consumption
from mytable t1 left join
mytable t2
on t2.item = (select max(item) from
                 mytable where item < t1.item)
order by t1.item asc
```

Note: this code will also work if your item codes do not increase by 1 every time (example you have item 1, 5, 7 ,8 it will calculate difference between 5 -1, 7 - 5 and 8-7

EDIT: code also works on sql-server

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2012+:

```
CREATE TABLE #foobar (item INT, d DATE, reading INT);

INSERT INTO #foobar
        ( item, d, reading )
VALUES  
    (1, '2015-06-01', 10),
    (2, '2015-06-02', 20),
    (3, '2015-06-03', 25);

SELECT *, COALESCE(reading - LAG(reading) OVER (ORDER BY d), 0)
FROM #foobar
```